# Off-target % for whole-exome sequencing panel

Tags: ngs, sam, wes

My samples have been sequenced with the Twist Exome 2.0 sequencing panel, and I want to assess how efficient the sequencing has been. By efficient, I mean examining metrics such as the uniformity (fold-80 score), coverage, on/off-target % etc. as documented in their webpage. I checked the % off-target as follows:

1. Count the # of reads in the bam file (`samtools view -c "$dir/$base.bam`)
2. Count the # of reads that intersect with the bed region (`bedtools intersect -a "$dir/$base.bam" -b $bed -u | samtools view -c -`)
3. Calculate the % off-target rate as (`bc -l <<< "(1 - ($bed_reads / $total_reads)) * 100"`)

I have two questions:

1. Is there a cleaner/simpler way to calculate the off-target rate? I know I can calculate the on-target rate with `bedtools coverage`, but I am not sure of how to calculate the off-target rate with a single command line.
2. I obtained an off-target rate of approximately 20-25% for my samples. Is this within the "good" off-target % range?